# Ошибка при компиляции программы, использующей Boost Multiprecision, в mingw

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

Возникла у меня тут необходимость в вычислениях с произвольной точностью и решил я использовать Boost Multiprecision. Я скачал Boost 1.77 и попробовал скомпилировать с использованием mingw такую вот программу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Эта программа не скомпилировалась. Компилятор выдал ошибку:

> C:\include\boost\math\special_functions\detail\bernoulli_details.hpp|559|error:
> 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type|
> C:\include\boost\math\special_functions\detail\bernoulli_details.hpp|21|note:
> 'std::mutex' is defined in header ''; did you forget to
> '#include mutex'?

ну и так далее. Заглянув в bernoulli_details.hpp, я увидел это:

```
#ifdef BOOST_HAS_THREADS
std::mutex m_mutex;
atomic_counter_type m_counter, m_current_precision;
#else
int m_counter;
int m_current_precision;
#endif // BOOST_HAS_THREADS
```

Немного удивившись тому, что в файле, где, по идее, должны считаться числа Бернулли, написано такое, я решил, что надо найти конфигурационный файл и убрать `#define BOOST_HAS_THREADS`. Мне не нужна многопоточность. Числа Бернулли мне, кстати, тоже не нужны. Как вы догадываетесь, я потерпел неудачу... Файлов, где определяется `BOOST_HAS_THREADS`, оказалось 18 штук. Часть из них - конфигурационные файлы платформ, остальное - файлы из разных математических библиотек Boost, где этот макрос переопределяется безусловно. Модифицировать все эти файлы, наверное, не стоит, да и смысла нет. Я удивился повторно и хочу спросить: можно ли всё-таки как-то откомпилировать мою программу в mingw или лучше бросить эту затею и юзать Visual Studio? В идеале хотелось бы как-то отключить многопоточность, раз уж для этого есть макрос и в mingw она сломана.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> многопоточность ... в mingw-w64 ... сломана

Ничего не сломано. В обычном MinGW (не w64) ее, вроде, до сих пор не подвезли, но в MinGW-w64 все должно работать.

Не надо руками ковыряться в бусте. Делаете вот что:

- Сносите все версии MinGW, которые у вас стоят.
- Устанавливаете MSYS2 и ставите MinGW оттуда, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/2752075).
- Оттуда же ставите буст, командой `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost`
- Дальше все должно работать из коробки.

Comment: Ну что-то же всё-таки сломано, иначе бы оно работало :)

Comment: @AVK Может вы обычный mingw поставили, вместо w64?

Comment: Вы правы, черт возьми. У меня они оба стояли, я компилировал mingw. Сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: Извините за введение в заблуждение

Comment: C mingw-w64 всё нормально

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - спасибо и от меня, Ваши советы не перый раз выручают!

Comment: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost` насчет `x86_64` я бы поспорил, мало ли юзер будет использовать `ucrt64`

Comment: @Kotomi Не хочется вот так сразу напрягать ТСа объяснениями про все 5 (или сколько их) окружений. Кажется, что mingw64 - нормальный дефолтный выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно установить MinGW с многопоточностью posix.

```
PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-boost> g++.exe .\some.c++ -I .\boost_1_77_0\
In file included from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/traits/is_variable_precision.hpp:9,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/precision.hpp:9,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:11,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:13,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp:9,
                 from .\some.c++:2:
.\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/number_base.hpp:92:21: warning: thread_local on mingw is broken, please use MSys mingw gcc-9 or later, see https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/
 #pragma GCC warning "thread_local on mingw is broken, please use MSys mingw gcc-9 or later, see https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/"
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Вот конфигурационная информация того варианта mingw-w64, который успешно собрал вашу программу.

```
PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-boost> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\Software\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/Software/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

Вариант mingw-w64 с многопоточностью win32 не определяет `std::mutex`:

```
PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-boost> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\Software\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/Software/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ...
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

PS C:\Users\User\tmp\try-boost> g++ .\some.c++ -I .\boost_1_77_0\
In file included from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/traits/is_variable_precision.hpp:9,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/precision.hpp:9,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:11,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:13,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp:9,
                 from .\some.c++:2:
.\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/detail/number_base.hpp:92:21: warning: thread_local on mingw is broken, please use MSys mingw gcc-9 or later, see https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/
 #pragma GCC warning "thread_local on mingw is broken, please use MSys mingw gcc-9 or later, see https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/527/"
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/math/special_functions/bernoulli.hpp:16,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:35,
                 from .\boost_1_77_0/boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp:24,
                 from .\some.c++:2:
.\boost_1_77_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/bernoulli_details.hpp:559:9: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
    std::mutex m_mutex;
         ^~~~~
```